# SQL server restore failure for Umbraco Database (exclusive access can't be obtained) - a process keeps getting connected

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, restore

I've set my DB into restricted user mode.  I'm trying to restore it from a backup, but get the following error:

Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

Get the same error in single user mode

There's a process connected, however every time I kill it off, a process with a different SPID connects.  Is this expected or is this the issue (I'm no DBA!)

I've tried:

- Googling for a solution :)
- detaching the DB (fails with a similar error about a lock on the DB)

I'm nervous to drop the DB (it's only UAT, but still...)

What next?

Answer (score 1):

The proper procedure is described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx

Comment: Thanks - that's something different, that put the DB into read-only mode, but still getting the same issue with the restore

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow Maybe it would help if you posted the precise error message you're receiving.  I've gone though this process dozens of times, and for the same reasons your're doing it.   Perhaps something else is going on:  did you check the error logs, too?   There's always the last-ditch approach of stopping the database server, but that will affect users in other DBs as well...

Answer (score 0):

OK this doesn't fix it for me however I came across this to kill off all processes, which is a nice script, as it identified that there were two processes connected and killed them in one hit - maybe it will do the trick for anyone else with the same issue:

```
declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int
select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid = db_id('LesMillsCmsUat') 
and spid != @@spid    

while (@spid is not null)
begin
    print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
    set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
    exec (@sql)

    select 
        @spid = min(spid)  
    from 
        master..sysprocesses  
    where 
        dbid = db_id('LesMillsCmsUat') 
        and spid != @@spid
end 

print 'Process completed...'
```

and this script successfully took the DB offline where doing this via the UI had failed - still didn't resolve things for me though - still the same restore problem:

```
alter database LesMillsCmsUat set offline with rollback immediate
alter database LesMillsCmsUat
set online
go
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is I had to stop the app pool used by Umbraco (which is what the DB was for), and just before this I had also stopped and restarted the DB server according to Curt's suggestion (remember now, this has resolved a similar issue for me in the past, although I'm not sure this really had any effect in my case and may not have been necessary).

Reasoning: Obviously Umbraco kept connecting.  Usually setting the DB to restricted user works as the account used by the Umbraco app won't have elevated permissions to then be able to connect to the DB, so I don't understand why I needed to stop the pool.  If anyone can provide the reason for this, this is the 'reason' I've really been looking for, and I'll mark it as the answer.